# Insert Comma Separated Values into MYSQL + Additional Form Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows users to tag an image, choose a location from a drop-down, & upload the image. The tagging takes place by allowing multiple values, separated by commas, to be entered into a field.

This code is successfully inputting the comma delimited list to individual rows:

```
    $categories = $_POST['bib'];
    $categories = explode(",", $categories);
    foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category = trim($category); // Remove possible whitespace
    $sql = "INSERT INTO athletes (bib) VALUES ('%s')";
    $sql = sprintf($sql, mysql_real_escape_string($category));
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

However, it is not adding the additional content (location from drop-down list & image filename).  For query purposes I need to be able to use both the 'bib' tag and the 'location' to be attached to images to allow users to search.

Before implementing the comma-separated option, this code was working to insert all of the data:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `athletes` VALUES ('$id', '$bib', '$race','$new_file_name')") ;
```

So, basically I'm trying to merge the functionality of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MySQL's [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement to update data in an existing row.